# Closure of commutator subgroup of absolute Galois group of $\Bbb Q$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, galois-theory

Let $G_\Bbb Q$ be the absolute Galois group of $\Bbb Q$, class field theory describes the structure of $G_\Bbb Q^{ab}$. But I feel something strange about the definition of $G_\Bbb Q^{ab}$: Is $[G_\Bbb Q,G_\Bbb Q]$ a closed subgroup of $G_\Bbb Q$?

Comment: As mentioned in _[Field and Galois Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=x_DjBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA170#v=onepage&q&f=false)_ by P. Morandi, we have $\mathrm{Gal}(\Bbb Q^{\mathrm{ab}} / \Bbb Q) \cong G_{\Bbb Q} / \overline{ [G_{\Bbb Q}, G_{\Bbb Q}] }$. In general, the quotient of a Hausdorff group by a non-closed subgroup might not be Hausdorff (see $\Bbb R / \Bbb Q$), while any profinite group is Hausdorff.

Comment: This is true if we replace $\Bbb Q$ by $\Bbb Q_p$ (see [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2844964/absolute-galois-group-of-bbb-q-p-while-varying-p#comment5868986_2845265)).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is not true in general, that the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ of a profinite group $G$ is a closed subgroup:

[Is the commutator subgroup of a profinite group closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637512/is-the-commutator-subgroup-of-a-profinite-group-closed)

So the quotient
$$
G_K/[G_K,G_K]
$$
is by the closure of the (usual algebraic) commutator subgroup
of $G_K$, the smallest subgroup which gives an abelian quotient.